# Providing a google search facility to a text box in java windows application

Tags: java

can we provide a google search facility to a text box in java windows application..

Comment: Everything is possible if you can program. It would be more useful if you elaborate what you failed. What code do you have as far? What happens? What happens not? Asking a rhetorical yes-no question "Can we do X?" isn't going to yield much useful response.

Comment: i am having no idea just asking the idea alone. Just this out. 
http://www.google.com/uds/samples/apidocs/helloworld.html

this is used to add the google search box in our web site. But i want to know whether we can add this to our java application also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Jakarta Commons HttpClient to submit the search request to Google, and read the result.  Then, you can use Swing's ability to do DOM processing and render HTML to display the results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Yes, you can.